# C# How to merge same type object in array

Tags: c#, arrays, xamarin.forms

I have an array of objects.
I want to create array statements like **"Go right from A to B"**
But for the same direction, I want to create a single statement like **"Go left from J to M"**
I got all same type of direction but not able to merge in the single statement as I required.
How to merge the same content from an array and create new instruction array? 
I have the array structure as below :

```
[  
   {  
      "label":"A",
      "direction":"right"
   },
   {  
      "label":"B",
      "direction":"right"
   },
   {  
      "label":"C",
      "direction":"left"
   },
   {  
      "label":"D",
      "direction":"slight right"
   },
   {  
      "label":"E",
      "direction":"slight right"
   },
   {  
      "label":"F",
      "direction":"left"
   },
   {  
      "label":"G",
      "direction":"back"
   },
   {  
      "label":"H",
      "direction":"slight right"
   },
   {  
      "label":"I",
      "direction":"slight right"
   },
   {  
      "label":"J",
      "direction":"left"
   },
   {  
      "label":"K",
      "direction":"left"
   },
   {  
      "label":"L",
      "direction":"left"
   },
   {  
      "label":"M",
      "direction":"left"
   },
   {  
      "label":"N",
      "direction":"straight"
   },
   {  
      "label":"O",
      "direction":"straight"
   },
   {  
      "label":"P",
      "direction":"straight"
   }
]
```

My code here :

```
 var temp = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i < array.Count - 1)
            {
                var start = array[i];
                var next = array[i + 1];

                if (!(start.direction.Equals(next.direction)))
                {
                    string instruction = $"Go {direction} from {start.label} towards {next.label}";
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Go {direction} from {start.label} towards {next.label}");
                      instructionList.Add(instruction);
            //Assign new next node to temp 
                     temp = next;
                }
                else
                {
                    string instruction = $"Go {direction} from {temp.label} towards {next.label}";

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Go {direction} from {temp.label} towards {next.label}");

                    //Same direction start and end label
                    //Here how to merge the same instruction into single

                    instructionList.add(instruction);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: use `Linq` to get the result in a Group manner(i.e. separate group for Right, left,etc.) and then do what you want with the particular group.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I get this right
We have the instructions
Go right from A -> B
Go right from B -> C
Now we want to merge them to
Go right from A -> C

The for loop seems fine. But inside it, the logic doesn't seem entirely correct.
  If the current instruction and the next have the same direction, we don't want to
do anything. The temporary variable already stores the instruction where the direction first went this way.
  If the current instruction and the next have different directions, we want to add an instruction going the current direction from the temporary variable to the next one. Then set the temporary variable as the next instruction.

To make sure that the temporary variable isn't null at the first direction swap, set it to the first instruction before the for loop, and not null.

```
var temp = array[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i < array.Count - 1)
            {
                var start = array[i];
                var next = array[i + 1];

                if (!(start.direction.Equals(next.direction)))
                {
                      string instruction = $"Go {direction} from {temp.label} towards {next.label}";
                      instructionList.Add(instruction);
            //Assign new next node to temp 
                     temp = next;
                }
            }
        }
```

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

Some instructions are obscure.

```
void Main()
{
    Directions[] directions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Directions[]>(GetJson());
    List<Instruction> instructions = new List<Instruction>();
    var direction = directions[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < directions.Length; i++)
    {
        if (directions[i].Direction != direction.Direction)
        {
            instructions.Add(new Instruction { StartPoint = direction.Label, EndPoint = directions[i - 1].Label, Direction = direction.Direction });
            direction = directions[i];
        }
    }
    instructions.Add(new Instruction { StartPoint = direction.Label, EndPoint = directions[directions.Length - 1].Label, Direction = direction.Direction });

    foreach (var i in instructions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Go {i.Direction} from {i.StartPoint} to {i.EndPoint}");     
    }
}

public class Instruction
{ 
    public string StartPoint { get; set; }
    public string EndPoint { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
}
public class Directions
{
    [JsonProperty("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("direction")]
    public string Direction { get; set; }
}


private string GetJson()
{  
    return @"
   [
   {  
      ""label"":""A"",
      ""direction"":""right""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""B"",
      ""direction"":""right""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""C"",
      ""direction"":""left""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""D"",
      ""direction"":""slight right""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""E"",
      ""direction"":""slight right""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""F"",
      ""direction"":""left""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""G"",
      ""direction"":""back""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""H"",
      ""direction"":""slight right""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""I"",
      ""direction"":""slight right""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""J"",
      ""direction"":""left""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""K"",
      ""direction"":""left""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""L"",
      ""direction"":""left""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""M"",
      ""direction"":""left""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""N"",
      ""direction"":""straight""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""O"",
      ""direction"":""straight""
   },
   {
    ""label"":""P"",
      ""direction"":""straight""
   }
]";
}
```